# product not showing on cateogry page after migration from Magento 2.2.4 to Magento 2.4.0

Tags: magento2

I have updated **Magento 2.2.4** to **Magento 2.4.0**. After that products are not showing on category page. please note when i search products were showing and also product details page is opening.

Please see the screenshot:

[image]

I have tried indexing , creating inventory view, tried creating new product and category, stock is also fine, product also assigned to website. Elastic search also configured as required .

I also tried to print to print the collection query on **ListProduct.php**

and I get this

```
"SELECT `e`.*, `price_index`.`price`, `price_index`.`tax_class_id`, `price_index`.`final_price`, IF(price_index.tier_price IS NOT NULL, LEAST(price_index.min_price, price_index.tier_price), price_index.min_price) AS `minimal_price`, `price_index`.`min_price`, `price_index`.`max_price`, `price_index`.`tier_price`, IFNULL(review_summary.reviews_count, 0) AS `reviews_count`, IFNULL(review_summary.rating_summary, 0) AS `rating_summary`, `stock_status_index`.`stock_status` AS `is_salable` FROM `catalog_product_entity` AS `e` INNER JOIN `catalog_product_index_price` AS `price_index` ON price_index.entity_id = e.entity_id AND price_index.customer_group_id = 0 AND price_index.website_id = '1' LEFT JOIN `review_entity_summary` AS `review_summary` ON e.entity_id = review_summary.entity_pk_value AND review_summary.store_id = 1 AND review_summary.entity_type = (SELECT `review_entity`.`entity_id` FROM `review_entity` WHERE (entity_code = 'product')) INNER JOIN `cataloginventory_stock_status` AS `stock_status_index` ON e.entity_id = stock_status_index.product_id WHERE (NULL)"
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem you described, tried the same steps you outlined, tracked down the same collection query. Ultimately the cause was a product attribute added by a third-party extension, said attribute was improperly configured.

Try the resolution explained here — https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/322623/36384